# How to add OpenSL ES library as a dependency to a project?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, opensl

I have started adding OpenSL ES code to my Dynamic Shared Library project, but when I try to compile it, linker says:

```
undefined reference to 'slCreateEngine'
```

I can see `OpenSLES.h` in "External Dependencies", but linker cannot see it somehow. This is the code:

```
#include "Processing.h"
#include <SLES/OpenSLES.h>
#include <SLES/OpenSLES_Android.h>

extern "C" {
    int Java_com_example_Android_MainPageViewModel_GetValue()
    {
        SLObjectItf engine_obj;
        slCreateEngine(&engine_obj, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

        return 42;
    }
}
```

How can I add NDK library to Dynamic Shared Library project in Visual Studio?